# Why does value assignment silently fail or do the wrong thing and how can I stop it from doing so

Tags: python, pandas

I had a very hard time finding a bug that basically boiled down to the fact that
the third line in

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(4),'b':np.random.random(4)})
df.values[1:-1] = [[0.1]*2]*2
```

has no effect -- all rows are unchanged.
While it makes at least some sense to prevent me from changing integers to floats (though I'd like to be able to circumvent this), this does not seem  to be the reason behind this behavior as

```
df.values[1:-1,1] = [0.1]*2
```

has no effect either! Curiously the third line in

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(4))})
df.values[1:-1] = [[0.1]]*2
```

does have an effect, although still not the one you'd expect -- the corresponding entries get set to zero! Again, this makes a tiny bit of sense, but I'd much rather get an exception than an implicit integer conversion.

I think this behavior should be changed or at least pandas should give me warnings that it's ignoring what I tell it to do. Before I go and open an issue about it on the github repo, however, I first wanted to ask for other opinions and more importantly, I wanted to ask:

**How can I reliably change subsets (row- and columnwise) of a DataFrame to take values of a given numpy array**
(I know that's a hacky endeavor, but that's how my data world is)

Comment: Don't use `.values` to try to modify the values, this returns a `np.array` of the values and this may or may be a view on the underlying data hence the odd behaviour you're seeing. You should use `.loc`, `iloc` etc for modifying

Comment: @EdChum Hm, I gave up on .iloc because when I tried only changing values in a single row, both `df.iloc[3] = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0.1],'b':[0.1]})` and `... = ....values` failed with `ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series` and `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`, respectively.

Comment: You need to know what you're doing, that fails because you're trying to assign a row using a df, this won't work. You're just assigning a scalar value so that will be broadcast along that row which is simple: `df.iloc[3] =  0.1`, if you intend to pass a row of different values: `df.iloc[3] = [1,2]` will work.

Comment: Yeah, also just realized that adding a `.squeeze()` fixes my problems. Thanks for the answer(s)

Comment: `squeeze` returns a flattened df as a `Series`, basically the dimensions of the value you're trying to assign from need to be broadcastable or can be aligned with the lhs, a df is a 2-D array this cannot be assigned to something which is a lower dimension such as a row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly don't call `.values` to assign to the data.

The reason for the difference in behaviour is that in your first example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(4),'b':np.random.random(4)})
```

column `'b'` is a view on the numpy array you passed as the data arg, as the constructor identifies this is a numpy array and for efficiency reasons the block manager can take a view on the array (there is no need to reconstruct an array and copy the data).

When you call `.values` this may or may not return a view on the underlying data.

When we call `.values`:

```
In[92]:
df.values

Out[92]: 
array([[0.        , 0.02512956],
       [1.        , 0.7394139 ],
       [2.        , 0.7535009 ],
       [3.        , 0.60658149]])
```

This is a numpy representation of the data, it may or may not be a view of the real underlying data.

In your case, it's returning a copy and not a view hence why this:

```
df.values[1:-1] = [[0.1]*2]*2
```

doesn't work.

However, if you use `iloc` then it does work:

```
df.iloc[1:-1] = [[0.1]*2]*2
```

In your second df, you're passing just a `range` so the data is constructed internally, no view is taken on the passed data unlike when you passed the numpy array. When you call `.values` this returns a view on the data and it just so happens to work, but it is not guaranteed to work. This is bad practice that you should avoid to avoid this ambiguity.

Comment: One last question if I may: Is there a reason why `df.iloc[1:-1] = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0.1,0.2],'b':[0.1,0.2]})` doesn't fail but instead assigns `NaN`s? I know that I can make this work by adding `.values` but this is one more thing that confused me about `iloc`

Comment: That fails because `df.iloc[1:-1]` selects rows `1` and `2`, you're assigning a newly created df whose index starts from `0`, so only row `1` is updated, row `2` because you selected it, but didn't assign to it, it was replaced with `NaN`, if the index matched: `df.iloc[1:-1] = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0.1,0.2],'b':[0.1,0.2]}, index=[1,2])` then it will overwrite at the desired location

Comment: Ah, how convenient, I could even have `index=[2,1]` and it would figure it out for me. So assigning with a dataframe rhs and an array rhs can both be useful in different ways

Comment: Basically pandas will try to use the index and align on the indices, it's confusing at first but this is one of the main advantages of pandas